# Отсутствует перевод заголовка "Community specific" при закрытии вопроса

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

Надо бы перевести

> Community specific

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 4):

Перевёл как:

- [Специфичный для сообщества](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/14499) (вопрос)

Ожидается в свежих ревизиях. Текущая rev 2020.9.15.37615

Comment: Что-то сомнительно выглядит...

Comment: @Qwertiy критикуешь — предлагай